# Convert result of division in degrees Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: functions

To convert degrees Celsius (x) into Fahrenheit (y), you'd do the following

```
y = (x * 9/5) + 32
```

Since the formula contains an offset (+ 32), we can't apply it when the value is a result of a calculation.

For example:
When x is the result of a difference (x = a - b), the formula becomes

```
y = [(a * 9/5) + 32] - [(b * 9/5) + 32]
y = (a * 9/5) + 32 - (b * 9/5) - 32
y = (a * 9/5) - (b * 9/5)
y = (a - b) * 9/5
y = x * 9/5
=> no more offset
```

or when x is the result of a sum (x = a + b)

```
y = [(a * 9/5) + 32] + [(b * 9/5) + 32]
y = (a * 9/5) + 32 + (b * 9/5) + 32
y = (a * 9/5) + (b * 9/5) + 32 + 32
y = [(a + b) * 9/5] + 32 + 32
y = (x * 9/5) + 32 + 32
=> twice the offset
```

But I can't figure out what formula to use when x is the result of a division (x = a / b).

Is it possible without knowing the values for "a" and "b"?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Simply replace $x$ with $a-b$ (or $a+b$) in the formula: $\frac95(a-b)+32$.

Comment: Why would someone multiply or divide temperatures? The scales are quite arbitrary: Something that's negative in another scale can be positive in another , and zero degrees is a common occurance ... Very suspicious.

Comment: @MattiP. It is part of a sofware program, where a user can create a "calculated input" based on two inputs. They have the possibility to choose to divide two temperatures. Not sure if or why anybody would do it.
The values and results are in Celsius, but they can choose to show it in Fahrenheit, that is why i would need the conversion

Comment: @Bernard I don't have the values for a or b, only the result x

Comment: @Kris: Then input $x$. I don't see what is the problem.

Comment: @Bernard when x is the result of a division of two temperatures in Celsius, I can't do x * 9/5 + 32 to convert to Fahrenheit, this will give a wrong result. Like I showed for addition and subtraction

Comment: But the result of a division has no dimensionl What is the physical meaning of this division?

Comment: @Bernard Lots of dimensionless things have physical meaning. Angles, for example, or Mach numbers.

Comment: The only kind of division of temperatures that has any physical meaning, as far as I know, is one absolute temperature divided by another. So you could convert both temperatures to Kelvins and then divide.

Comment: But once you divide then the result is dimensionless. You can't "show it in Fahrenheit." The same would be true if you were dividing one distance in meters by another. Only addition and subtraction preserve the dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is not possible.
I can't show the mathematics to prove it is not possible, but I can show an example:

If I have x = 5°C, as a result of the division of a = 50°C and b = 10°C, then it becomes in Fahrenheit

```
a = 50 * 9 / 5 + 32 = 122
b = 10 * 9 / 5 + 32 = 50
a / b = 122 / 50 = 2.44
```

but if x = 5°C as a result of the division a = 30°C and b = 6 °C

```
a = 30 * 9 / 5 + 32 = 86
b = 6 * 9 / 5 + 32 = 42.8
a / b = 86 / 42.8 = 2.0093
```

same x Celsius, two different results in Fahrenheit

so without knowing a and b, we can 't convert the result of a division

Comment: Think about the numbers as having units and quantities, and do [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis), i.e. keep track of units. Some scientific software I know has numbers with a Temperature quantity, and those could have units of C, F, K (Kelvin), or R (Rankin). They can be freely converted between those units, but not to units of another quantity like Pressure. There was also a quantity TemperatureDiff, for temperature differences. It has units KDiff=CDiff or FDiff=RDiff. Addition of Temperatures makes no sense, but Temperature+TDiff does.

Comment: Similarly dividing or multiplying temperatures rarely makes sense (even in Kelvin). If this user-defined formula is merely used for calculating some kind of weighting, or is some sort of correlation, then the user must also specify which units the terms are specified in, precisely because such correlations or weightings often completely defy dimensional analysis. In other words - pass on the problem to the user.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Actually, _temperature ratio,_ the dimensionless ratio of two absolute temperatures, is widely used in aerospace applications (https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/BGH/isentrop.html). Ratios of temperatures in arbitrary scales such as Celsius or Fahrenheit are not so useful, of course.